# Cannot type [ in Notepad++ (in TeamViewer)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, teamviewer

I cannot type `[` in notepad++. It collapses the current level of code instead 
- it does the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>. Right bracket `]` normally just types it. I have no idea how this happened. It was working well before! Could I do it somehow accidentally? How can I fix this?

I looked into Settings > Shortcut mapper but the mappings of the Collapse function seem allright:

[image]

PS: restarting Notepad++ didn't help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Notepad++ didn't help, but it did help to restart TeamViewer! (I have the R-session open through TeamViewer).